# Unable to print scope variable inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to associate id inside an ng-repeat loop. Can someone suggest how can i do this?

here is the code

```
<li ng-repeat="agent in agents">
     <chart chart-id={{agent}}></chart>
</li>
```

Note: Chart is my directive.

Comment: Can you show up what your directive code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your directive looks something like this:

```
app.directive('chart', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       scope: {
           chartId: '='
       },
       template: '<div>Agent {{chartId.name}} reporting for duty</div>'
   }
}
```

You just need to update your code, dropping the curly brackets and adding quotes:

```
<li ng-repeat="agent in agents">
    <chart chart-id="agent"></chart>
</li>
```

Comment: Yes Chris, My directive looks like the same that you mentioned. But it does not append actual agent values. It still shows up <chart chart-id="agent"> </chart>

Comment: Here is what agents array looks like $scope.agents = ["chart1", "chart2", "chart3"]

Comment: If you're looking at the DOM only, it is a little confusing because angular won't modify that part of the DOM - check out http://jsbin.com/atunaka/1/ for an example and inspect the list in the output.

Comment: I guess so. So if i want to display the values inside any html element it does appear, however if i associate it with any id it doesnt. looks like I will have to change my approach to achieve my usecase. Thanks